# AutoMapper entity collection partial update not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Basically I'm trying to do an update on an entity object that already exist in the database by changing it's values to match the values of the input object provided by the user. The entity object however has more properties than the input object (let's call them 'extra properties') and I want these 'extra properties' to remain with whatever values they had after the map, and only the properties that exist in both object to be overridden.

My problem is that I can do what I described above when I map a single input value to an entity, however, when a list of input values to an output of entities than the 'extra properties' of the entity are set to either 0 or null.

I believe the reason this is happening is because AutoMapper created brand new objects when trying to map a list of values and ignores the values on the destination object that have no corresponding values from the source object which cases them to have a default value.

I have written a simple console app the reproduces this problem in the ExampleB (I'm using the 6.1.0 version of AutoMapper which is the latest one at the time of writing this):

```
namespace TestEF
{
    using System;
    using AutoMapper;

    class Program
    {
        public class Input
        {
            public long One { get; set; }
        }

        public class Entity
        {
            public long One { get; set; }

            public long Two { get; set; }
        }

        static void CreateMaps()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Input, Entity>();
            });
        }

        static void ExampleA()
        {
            var input = new Input
            {
                One = 1
            };

            var entity = new Entity
            {
                One = -1,
                Two = 2
            };

            var res = Mapper.Map(input, entity);
            Console.WriteLine($"Example A: {res.One}: {res.Two}, Same object: {res == entity}");
        }

        static void ExampleB()
        {
            var inputList = new Input[]
            {
                new Input
                {
                    One = 1
                } 
            };

            var entityList = new Entity[]
            {
                new Entity
                {
                    One = -1,
                    Two = 2
                }
            };

            var res = Mapper.Map(inputList, entityList);
            Console.WriteLine($"Example B: {res[0].One}: {res[0].Two}. Same object: {res == entityList}. Same list item: {res[0] == entityList[0]}");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateMaps();

            ExampleA(); // This one works as expected

            ExampleB(); // This is where the problem is

            Console.Read(); // Stop the console from closing
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this problem so that when mapping list items, AutoMapper uses existing object rather than creating new ones (or at least if it creates new ones then to populate the values from the original object that are not part of the mapping)?